# Error error: Couldn't load configuration file, skipping BinDiff plugin

Tags: diff, ida

I have downloaded the [bindiff420-win-pluginsonly.zip](https://dl.google.com/dl/zynamics/bindiff420-win-pluginsonly.zip) file and unpacked it in a directory with plug-ins. After loading of IDA 6.9 I have noticed

> error: Couldn't load configuration file, skipping BinDiff plugin.

What have I missed?

Comment: Check out the reverse engineering stackexchange instead of SO.

Comment: You need to also download bindiff-license-key.zip.  Extract the contents  to a file named BinDiff.xml and place this file in the same plugin folder.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 comment your info in answer ) its work!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

download bindiff-license-key.zip. Extract the contents to a file named BinDiff.xml and place this file in the same plugin folder.